# Default App Permission Scope

Tags: workflow, rest

I've created a list that creates subsites through the REST API that uses a project site template. The site template i'm using has workflows that talk back to the main site using the REST API. The problem is I'm getting Access denied because the workflow has not yet been trusted outside the site scope. Is there a setting i can use to default the workflow to be trusted throughout the site collection so i don't have to manually trust each workflow as these subsites are created? Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks
Mark

Answer (score 0):

There is a site feature called **Workflows can use app permissions** that can be enabled allowing the workflows to be trusted.

Comment: Once that is enabled I still have to trust the workflow in the sitecollection scope via the _layouts/appinv.aspx page. Even after I wrap the step in an App Step inside the workflow.